# Elasticsearch multinode setup

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to setup an 3 node cluster setup in elasticsearch, but I unable to setup, getting error like connection refused in data machine, master machine starting fine, but it shows like 0 nodes added.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to read tutorial first, like

- https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-production-elasticsearch-cluster-on-ubuntu-14-04
- https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-discovery-zen.html

then ask precise question here about a specific issue.

About your question, I think you didnt configure `discovery.zen.ping.unicast.host` fine, so nodes dont know each other.

Also, when you post a question, please post:

- elasticsearch version
- environnement (AWS, VM ...)
- configuration sample

Welcome at SO!

Comment: Hi Thomos, I  went through the above tutorials what you shared, and i tried configuring the same way.

Comment: discovery.zen.ping.unicast.host I've give my two nodes ip address/ host names.

Comment: the Elasticsearch version I'm using 5.5.2 in all the 3 machines, Environment: Ubuntu 14

Comment: Make use all nodes can communicate via port 9200 & 9300 together and you can "curl NODE_X:9200" to see elasticsearch is started fine. Also you must set the 3 node IPs for all nodes ``discovery.zen.ping.unicast.host `` config.